# How can I activate control statement from gui button?

Tags: java

In this example, why doesn't the method activate if the variable was changed and the button is set up in another class?

```
public class Printing {

  static boolean print = false;

  public static void main(String[] args){
    new Gui().setVisible(true);
    print();
  }

  public static void print(){
    while (print) {
      System.out.println("true");
    }
  }
}
```

When the button is pressed it set the `boolean` print to `true` the method print doesn't activate and start printing true can anyone tell me why is this happening and how to solve this.

**EDIT FOR MY ASKED FOR CODE**

My Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;

public class Gui extends JFrame {
boolean print = false;
public Gui() {
    initComponents();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gui gui = new Gui();
    new Gui().setVisible(true);
    gui.Print();
}
public void Print(){
    while(print == true){
        System.out.println("Its true");
    }
}
private void buttonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   print = true;
}
private void initComponents() {
    button = new JButton();
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    button.setText("Push");
    button.addActionListener(e -> buttonActionPerformed(e));
    GroupLayout contentPaneLayout = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(contentPaneLayout);
    contentPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        contentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup()
            .addGroup(contentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(81, 81, 81)
                .addComponent(button, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 219,       GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(84, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    contentPaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        contentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup()
            .addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, contentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(144, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(button)
                .addGap(91, 91, 91))
    );
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());
}
private JButton button;
```

}

Comment: Do you call Print() in the event handler? Simply setting print = true won't actually call this method. Can you post the full code you're using (including the event handler for the button)?

Comment: Are you expecting the "print()" method's "while" loop to keep checking to see if the "print" variable has changed? Because it definitely won't.

Comment: Can you clarify why you think that the code in question *would* work?

Comment: I thought once the variable was changed by the button the method would activate

Comment: Right, but why do you think that it would have that effect? Were you assuming that, due to the "while" loop, the "print" method would continue to check to see if the "print" variable had become true yet in the background? Or that the JVM would provide some kind of event notification for the change? (Just asking to see if there's something I can clarify more in my answer).

Comment: Yes exacly how you said it, i thought that one the variable change since the method is in the main method one the button change the boolean it would activate.

Comment: You mean that the Print() method would continue to check the variable for updates or that changing the variable from Main() would notify the Print() method of the change?

Comment: Yes how would i get that to work

Comment: "Yes" to which option? If you want the first option (the Print() method continues to check the variable for updates) you want to use a background thread like Raffaele shows in his answer. If you want the class to provide some kind of event notification you need to implement the Observer pattern like in my post.

Comment: I want the Print method to continue checking for the variable, does the thread for just the method or for the whole project as a whole.

Comment: Just the Print method, see Raffaele's example for how to do this. One thing I'd recommend adding to his code is using Thread.sleep after checking (i.e. only check every half a second or however long rather than polling continuously) to save CPU cycles.

Comment: Good, glad we could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided in your question doesn't even compile so we can't understand what are the requirements. Anyway I'll assume that you want to keep printing while the flag is `true`, so you'll need a separate thread to run the printing routine:

```
public class Printer implements Runnable {

  public volatile boolean keepPrinting;

  public static void main(String... args) {
    Printer printer = new Printer();
    Gui gui = new Gui(printer);
    Thread t = new Thread(printer);
    t.start();
  }

  @Override public void run() {
    while (true) {
      if (keepPrinting) {
        System.out.println("It works!");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume he was thinking that his original print() method would behave like the code sample you provide here but it's hard to tell without further clarification from him. It seems like the Observer pattern would make a lot more sense here than just continuously polling and wasting CPU cycles.

Comment: You are right - it's *impossible* to tell. Just provided the code because OP can't even describe his problem, so a working program may be a good starting point

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason that it *should* do this. The "while" loop will definitely *not* cause the print() method to continue to monitor the "print" variable for changes in its state (unless you intended to put the print() method on on a background thread and have it poll continuously; I don't recommend this though). Otherwise, this'll check once and then won't check again until you explicitly call Print() again.

In order for a method to be called in response to a change of state of an object, you need to implement the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). There are a number of reasonable examples of this in Java (available on Google); I'd recommend getting an example in Java if that's your chosen language (as opposed to C#) because implementing the pattern in Java's a little more complicated in Java than it is in C# (C# uses *events*, which is a primitive built into the framework itself to support this). Basically, you'll get something like this (in pseudocode):

```
interface IObserver
{
   void MethodToCall(bool newValue);
}

public class SomeObservers implements IObserver
{
   public void MethodToCall(bool newValue)
   {
      // ...
   }
}

public class ObservedClass
{
   private List<IObserver> observers = new List<IObserver>();
   private bool observedValue;

   public bool getObservedValue() { return observedValue; }

   public bool setObservedValue(bool newValue)
   {
      observedValue = newValue;
      NotifyObservers();
   }

   public void RegisterObserver(IObserver observer)
   {
      observers.Add(observer);
   }

   public void RemoveObserver(IObserver observer)
   {
       observers.Remove(observer);
   }

   public void NotifyObservers()
   {
      // Notify each interested party about the change in the value
      foreach (IObserver observer in observers)
      {
         observer.MethodToCall(observedValue);
      }
   }
}
```